# Collect to ordered set in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

using Hive's built in collect_set, I was going to implement a query where I could reliably know that the arrays 0 index was the first element collected, and the last index was the last element collected. -Example:

```
cookie  page_num, 
1234      1 
1234      2 
1234      3 
1234      4 
4444      1
4444      2
```

Query:

```
select cookie, collect_set(page_num) as page_set 
from mytable  
group by cookie
```

Desired Reults:

```
1234  [1,2,3,4] 
4444  [1,2]
```

Actual un-ordered result:

```
1234 [2,4,1,3] 
4444 [2,1]
```

How can I collect to a sorted array where the sort is based on the order of incoming rows?

Answer (score 0):

The 'collect_max' UDF in Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) will order the map according to the values. ( Perhaps we should add a sort UDF as well).  You could use that, along with group_count to get what you want

```
SELECT cookie, map_keys( 
         collect_max( page_num, row_order, MAX_NUM_PAGES ) )
FROM (
    SELECT cookie, page_num, group_count( cookie ) as row_order
      FROM mutable
      DISTRIBUTE BY cookie
      SORT BY cookie, my_sort_column 
) sc
GROUP BY cookie;
```

I'm pretty sure that will work.

Comment: A udf for an array_sort would be great. I ended up using brickhouse collect, which when testing, seems to collect in the order the order of incoming rows. Will take a look at this, thanks.

Comment: I filed a JIRA, so sort_array may finally end up in Brickhouse